# How to trap SQLite error on first time run for an app

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

In the main activity I am trying to check when the app gets open if the app database exist or not. This is because I want to get a chance to create the database and insert all the needed records on the very first run only.

But it's not working with me, it give me this error:

..Caused by: android. database. CursorindexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0

My first thought is that the above exception/error is not SQLiteException or I don't know exactly what I am missing.

Here is my code:

```
    DBAdapter dbCheck = new DBAdapter(this);
    boolean dbStatus;
    String strData;
    try { 
        dbCheck.open(); 
        Cursor tblCheck = dbCheck.getThis_tblData(10); //get record no 10 - random number
        strData = tblCheck.getString(5);   // get the value of a field in the table
        tblCheck.close();
        dbCheck.close();
        System.out.println("<---> Db found ");
    } catch (SQLiteException e) { 
        //database doesn't exist yet. Create it.
        System.out.println("<---> Db not found ");
    Intent MakeDB = new Intent(MainActivity.this, com.kjsoft.tre.InsertData.class);
    StartActivity(MakeDB);
    }
```

Thanks everyone for your help!

Comment: test moveToFirst to begin with. your cursor looks empty. no idea why, since you didn't post the content of `getThis_tblData`

Comment: May be add catch all Exception catch(Exception e){....} and see.

Comment: You can use pre-populated database.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9109438/how-to-use-existing-database-with-android-app/9109728#9109728

Comment: @Nambari I like your idea, I will try it when I get to my PC.

Answer (score 0):

This particular exceptions happens in the generic `Cursor` class, so it's not an `SQLiteException`.

You could change the type in the `catch` statement, like Nambari said, but it is a better idea to create an
[SQLiteOpenHelper class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html)
to manage the creation of the DB (and updates, if your app ever changes).

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, yes I will try Nambari's idea.

Answer (score 0):

replace the following line in you code:

```
Cursor tblCheck = dbCheck.getThis_tblData(10);
```

with the following:

```
Cursor tblCheck = dbCheck.getThis_tblData(10);
if ((tblCheck != null) && (tblCheck.getCount() > 0)) {
    tblCheck.moveToNext();
    strData = tblCheck.getString(5);
}
```

the cursor initial position is always **just before the first row**, so you have to move it to the next step (the first row) and then access your data.
and of course, you have to check if it is not null.